Spring animation is causing ellipsis element to clip
I have a crosshair component in Vue that has a scan animation triggered when its state changes to scan. The problem is that when the ellipsis in the svg containing the scan animation scales above 1, it starts clipping. I'd like the prevent that. It doesn't clip if I remove mask='url(#mask0_0_1)' on the g element but then I lose the mask, which I need.
Crosshair.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
enum crosshairState {
  Default,
  Pulse,
  Scan
}
withDefaults(defineProps<{
  state?: crosshairState
  warningColors?: boolean
}>(), {
  state: crosshairState.Default
})
</script>

<template>
  <svg :class="{'hide': state === crosshairState.Scan}" width="400" height="338" viewBox="0 0 400 338" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: visible;" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <mask id="mask0_0_1" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="338">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M400 0H0V338H400V0ZM200.076 240.1C232.991 240.1 261.381 223.28 274.462 199H395V140H275.147C262.391 115.02 233.577 97.5947 200.076 97.5947C154.747 97.5947 118 129.496 118 168.848C118 208.199 154.747 240.1 200.076 240.1Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
      </mask>
      <g mask='url(#mask0_0_1)' style="overflow: visible;">
          <ellipse v-if="state === crosshairState.Scan" cx="218.674" cy="169.497" rx="171.674" ry="148.497" fill="none" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="2" :stroke="warningColors ? '#C02A4F' : '#95F39B'"/>
          <ellipse :class="{'pulse' : state === crosshairState.Pulse, 'scan': state === crosshairState.Scan, 'opacity-40': warningColors }" cx="218.674" cy="169.497" rx="171.674" ry="148.497" :fill="warningColors ? '#C02A4F' : '#95F39B'"/>
      </g>
      <path d="M275.299 140.3C262.621 115.16 233.711 97.5947 200.076 97.5947C154.747 97.5947 118 129.496 118 168.848C118 208.199 154.747 240.1 200.076 240.1C233.122 240.1 261.607 223.146 274.618 198.71" :stroke="warningColors ? '#C02A4F' : '#58C160'" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
      <rect :class="{'rect-pulse' : state === crosshairState.Pulse, 'rect-scan' : state === crosshairState.Scan}" x="271.3" y="136.3" width="119" height="8" rx="4" :fill="warningColors ? '#C02A4F' : '#58C160'"/>
      <rect :class="{'rect-pulse' : state === crosshairState.Pulse, 'rect-scan' : state === crosshairState.Scan}" x="271.3" y="194.71" width="119" height="8" rx="4" :fill="warningColors ? '#C02A4F' : '#58C160'"/>
  </svg>
</template>

<style>
  @keyframes pulseAnimation {
    0%, 100% {
      opacity: 0;
      rx: 0px;
      ry: 0px;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
      rx: 171.674px;
      ry: 148.497px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes rectPulseAnimation {
    0%, 100% {
      width: 0px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 119px;
    }
}
  @keyframes scanAnimation {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0;
      fill: #95F39B;
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      fill: #95F39B;
    }
    85% {
      transform: scale(1.3);
      fill: white;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
      fill: #95F39B;
    }
  }
  @keyframes rectScanAnimation {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        width: 125px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 119px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes hide {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  .pulse {
    animation: pulseAnimation 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .rect-pulse {
    animation: rectPulseAnimation 1.5s infinite;
  }
  .scan {
    animation: scanAnimation 3s ease forwards;
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .rect-scan {
    animation: rectScanAnimation 3s ease forwards;
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .hide {
    animation: hide 0.5s forwards;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
  }
</style>

Test.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const s = ref(1)
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="s=2">CLICK ME</button>
    <div class="fixed flex h-screen w-screen items-center justify-center">
        <CerameterCrosshair :state="s"/>
    </div>
</template>


Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Please post the plain HTML and CSS that results from your Vue component. That would make it a lot easier to answer your question.
